# How to scrape amazon search with php?

Tags: php, dom, curl, web-scraping

Any ideas? I am new to php and am having a lot of trouble with curl and domdocuments so please write or show me an example. I was thinking of using dom documents but I can not figure out how to get amazon to search a users input from my site and display certain parts of the results such as price, category ex.....

Comment: Why scrape when [Amazon provide an API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asking for a scraper to be written for them!

Comment: @Johnsyweb - There's good reasons to use the API but there's also good reasons not to. Not everything is available from the API and the keys are a pain to get.

Comment: @pguardiario: Sure. Which is partially why I asked the question.

Comment: The API does not work anymore unless you have regular confirmed sales (which is hard to do when you're setting up a site)

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods using file_get_contents, a "save html" plugin (https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/) and CURL which I've had varying luck with, but eventually it starts flagging my requests with robot checks. I originally used the API, but Amazon locked that down to minimum traffic rules that I can't meet with my budding webservice rendering that useless.

There currently is no easy/effective way to consistently pull Amazon data though I'm playing with randomizing useragents and using proxies.

Answer (score -1):

Use the Product Advertising API instead of scraping.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html

Comment: This no longer works. The API is restricted to people who have confirmed minimum "impressions" (sales) per month (which is hard to do when you can't use an API so... not sure what they're thinking there.

Answer (score -1):

The product API actually would be the best resource for this although it gives you limited results and after 180 days if no affiliate transaction occurs I believe they may revoke your access so it does limit you to some extent depending on your uses. Not sure but I think you may need a professional seller account or an affiliate membership, not 100% on that but that is my understanding.

Comment: That is correct though it's way less than 180 days and there's a minimum amount that is hard to reach so API is basically useless unless you're already running a site with significant traffic to Amazon.